Azure CosmosDB run in parallel few workers calling same stored procedure
Is it possible to run multiple workers in parallel, calling the same stored procedure in CosmosDB?
I have a bulkDelete stored procedure, almost identical to this one, and a C# console app that calls this procedure, let's say with 2 workers.
Each worker has its own list of partition keys, so they work on non-overlapping partitions.
However, based on the logs, I notice that 1 worker achieves the same deletion speed as 2 or more workers.
Is this even possible? If yes, how would you implement it?
I need to delete more that 500+ millions items from the DB, so I'm searching for the fastest approach.

You should probably look at this answer which points out that bulk delete, as you're doing in a stored procedure, is not a good idea. Aside from that: there are no specific details in your question - just a general performance behavior you're seeing.
